# How to remove animation from credit card form?

Tags: android, animation, credit-card

I am using https://github.com/dbachelder/CreditCardEntry sdk for my credit card validation, but when i set card number to CreditCardForm it is vibrating and showing red color hint text. can any one help to remove such type of animation?

```
import com.devmarvel.creditcardentry.library.CreditCardForm;

CreditCardForm.setCardNumber("************4242",false);
```

and my build.gradle is,

```
compile 'com.github.dbachelder:CreditCardEntry:1.4.7'
```

Comment: animate_on_error and default_text_colors should get you going on the right direction.

Comment: Thank you @PsyGik. I removed compile 'com.github.dbachelder:CreditCardEntry:1.4.7' from my build.gradle and add library project into module dependency, and then i use animate_on_error in my xml file. finally its work.

Comment: Good job. Now post the answer so that others can see how you solved it.

Answer (score 1):

use **app:animate_on_error** for add or remove animation to the CreditCardForm

```
<com.devmarvel.creditcardentry.library.CreditCardForm
                        android:id="@+id/form_no_zip"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        app:card_number_hint="XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX"
                        app:include_zip="false"
                        app:animate_on_error="false"
                        app:default_text_colors="@color/your_color_here"
                        app:helper_text_color="@color/your_color_here"
                        />
```

and add in your main layout `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`